# Neater version of print_r($_POST)

Tags: php

I'm trying to creating a php program that simply does the same thing as `print_r()`, but in a neater format.  I created a form that just has some checkboxes and radio buttons and when the user hits the **submit** button, it takes them to another page that shows them the values of what they picked.  I planned on using a foreach statement, but I'm having trouble with the syntax.  Here's what I came up with in my pseudocode

```
foreach($_POST as X=>Y)
    echo ("For ".X." you entered ".Y."<br>");
```

What I'm unsure of is what `X` and `Y` would be.  Is there a way I can read the `print_r($_POST)` into a variable and display it how I want to?

Comment: "What I'm unsure of is what X and Y would be" — variables … with normal variable syntax.

Comment: `foreach` is described pretty well in manual. Check it.

Comment: "Is there a way I can read the print_r($_POST) into a variable and display it how I want to?" — In to a variable as what? As a string of not-very-well-structured data that you'd have to parse to figure out which parts were formatting and which parts were data?!

Comment: you can also just wrap print_r in `<pre>` tags so it's easier to read.

Comment: I know X and Y would be variables, but I'm not sure what I'm setting them as.  Sorry for the poor wording.  I'd like one to be a variable for each field, and the other to be a variable for each value entered.  I'm very new new to php (to put it lightly) so I think I'm missing the syntax for this.

Comment: I ended up going with Kai's suggestiong.  Thank you.  I think I'm trying to get too fancy with something I don't have enough of an understanding of.

Answer (score 1):

A nicer way is to get xdebug module and turn on HTML display (see http://xdebug.org/docs/display) and it will make it look nicer.

You could also look at kurmo http://krumo.sourceforge.net which is a nice tree view of print_r